# Is this image from the TensorFlow documentation correct?

Tags: tensorflow

On the indicator column for row **#32** the down arrow indicating where position **30** is shows "..." but then just one more item in the array over to the right there's a **1**.

Doesn't that make it key and in this case also value of **31** instead?

Why is it that **32** is thirty one positions after the beginning, when **0** is **0**?

---

[image]

Comment: Yes that should be `#31` rather than `#32`. The other items are correct.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find that? Please provide a link and a quote with the essential parts.

Comment: It was found near the bottom of this section: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/feature_columns#indicator_and_embedding_columns